# Making keyup event more responsive

Tags: wpf, keyup

```
 <TextBox FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"   TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Collapsed" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Grid.Row="0" x:Name="sessionNoteContent" KeyUp="SaveNote">

 private void SaveNote(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionNoteContent.Text))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Class1 note = new Class1 ()
                       {
                        time1=timeElapsed,
                        Notes = sessionNoteContent.Text, 
                        StartTime = sessionStartTime, 
                       CurrentTimestamp = DateTime.Now,
                       TeamId = teamId,
                 };
                repo.InsertSessionNote(note);
                sessionNoteListData.Add(note);



                sessionNoteContent.Text = "";



            }
            sessionNoteContent.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            sessionNotesList.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

I have handled key up event on my texbox. It slows down the display of characters when I type . Is there some wayto handle it. Working on  wpf desktop application.

Comment: Handling Key Up event should not slow down of displaying the characters. Could you please share your code.

Comment: added the code in the question

Comment: In this case it'll be slow down only when you press Enter because your doing lot of things on enter not for all the keys. It is slow on enter key because your doing a time consuming operation. Just check whether you need to do this when ever enter is pressed. If so try to do it in thread